# Java: Adding a user input to while loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to put a while loop in PlayerOne class, where it would be possible with the user input to choose a profession of a player. I'm not sure how to get it to work. Can you give me a suggestion or a hint? Thank you! (I suppose you don't need a Player class or Main class, so I'll leave them out of the way)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
         System.out.println("Choose your profession: \n" +
        "Press 1 for a knight class\n" +
        "Press 2 for a rider class\n" +
        "Press 3 for a mage class");
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
            // here I want to put an option to choose a knight by pressing number 1
            break;
        case 1:
            // an option to choose a rider by pressing number 2
            break;
case 1:
            // an option to choose a mage by pressing number 3
            break;
```

Comment: You can get the input in every 'case' the same way you are getting the input at start. Make sure you have 'default' case and all the cases should be unique. You cant have two cases for choice '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a stop condition for your while when someone choose a valid profession, like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String profession = null;
while (profession == null) {
    System.out.println("Choose your profession: \n" +
        "Press 1 for a knight class\n" +
        "Press 2 for a rider class\n" +
        "Press 3 for a mage class");
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            profession = "knight";
            break;
        case 2:
            profession = "rider";
            break;
        case 3:
            profession = "mage";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option");
            profession = null;
            break;
    }
}
System.out.println("You selected: "+profession+" class.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String profession= null;
    while (profession == null) {
        System.out.println("Choose your profession: \n" +
                "Press 1 for a knight class\n" +
                "Press 2 for a rider class\n" +
                "Press 3 for a mage class");
        String choice = scanner.nextLine();

        if (choice.equals("1")){
            profession = "knight";
            System.out.println("You selected: "+profession+" class.");
        }else if (choice.equals("2")){
            profession = "rider";
            System.out.println("You selected: "+profession+" class.");
        }else if (choice.equals("3")){
            profession = "mage";
            System.out.println("You selected: "+profession+" class.");
        }else {
            System.out.println("invaild option");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi :), could you add a little description to your answer?

Comment: you can also use if statement :)